# When does billing begin when an Autonomous Database is cloned, and end when it is terminated?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

When does billing begin when an Autonomous Database is cloned, and end when it is terminated?

If there is a large amount of data in an Autonomous Database, it can take some time to clone the database (for example up to an hour for a 7TB database).

When cloning happens, when precisely does billing for the clone start? Is it when the user clicks the Clone button, or when the provisioning is completed?

Similarly, when an Autonomous Database is terminated, does billing stop as soon as the user presses the Terminate button, or when termination is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Billing starts (or stops) whenever the control plane sees its action as ‘succeeded’. So even if it takes time to create a clone, the clone is not billable until it is running.

Termination will stop billing quickly even if the full termination process takes some time.